# Oracle performance with function in select

Tags: oracle

In my production enviroment i have a significative difference when i call a function directly in select and when i "wrap" the select and then call then function outside (below i show you two simple example)

In the first case (when the function is called directly) the result query end in 35 seconds.

In the second case (function wrapped) the result end in 7 seconds.

Sure, the query is exatcly the same and the result rows are the same too.

There is a difference (in performance) calling the same function in the two ways?

**SLOW VERSION:**

```
select col1, col2, myFun(col3)
  from aTable;
```

**FAST VERSION**

```
select col1, col2, myFun(col3)
  from (select col1, col2, col3
          from aTable);
```

Comment: are you sure that is the real query? no `WHERE` or `JOIN` or something like that?

Comment: @Mistre83: Did you try doing an `EXPLAIN` on both statements?

Comment: what exactly does the function? what is the exec plan? how many times is the function executed?

Comment: The real query is very "big", i've just wrote the "concept". @SameerMirji explain is significative if i have function in statement ?

Comment: The function i can say that is fast, but when is directly in select (example 1) the performance are very slow. When i take it outside performance are faster. Oracle compute the results in two different way when the function is called outside as in the Example 2 ?

Comment: @Mistre83: Possible. You will find that out exactly with the `EXPLAIN PLAN`.. ;)

Comment: I've tried  just now to do EXPLAIN PLAN in both version and the result is bizarre... In the first case (slow one) i have the full explain but with no cost. In the second case (the fast one) i have the cost... Really dont know why in the first case i dont get the cost....

Comment: Also beware, do not call SQL from function which is called from SQL. Not only that you might face performance problems but also such a query usually gives unpredictable results.

Comment: if you run fast version query at once after slow version maybe  reason in removing disk reads? Because in this case all blocks was contained in buffer cache and access to data was faster. Try to execute fast version at first and slow version after to check my version ;) Thanks)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose there are 1 million rows in aTable, but your real query has a WHERE clause that returns only 10 rows:

```
select col1, col2, myFun(col3)
  from aTable
  join ...
  join ...
 where ...;
```

Oracle **may** decide to call the function myFun before joining and filtering, so it will be called 1 million times.  Calling PL/SQL functions from SQL is slow due to context switching.

When you wrap it like this:

```
select col1, col2, myFun(col3)
  from (select col1, col2, col3
          from aTable
          join ...
          join ...
          where ...
       );
```

... now Oracle is **probably** going to perform the joins and filtering first, get 10 rows back, and then call myFun 10 times.

If each function call takes 0.001 seconds, then this will take 1,000,000*0.001 = 1,000 seconds for the first query, and 10*0.001 = 0.01 seconds for the second wrapped query.

Note that I said **may** and **probably** - the optimiser can make different choices depending on the statistics - so for some queries both versions may call the function only 10 times, or both call it 1 million times.

This hint should ensure that the second version is always fast, by telling Oracle not to merge the two queries into one:

```
select /*+ no_merge(v) */ col1, col2, myFun(col3)
  from (select col1, col2, col3
          from aTable
          join ...
          join ...
          where ...
       ) v;
```

Comment: I have supposed this too... maybe in the first version the function is appied to each row and in the second version the function is applied on the result (that with join/where) the rows are less. Thanks!